# Getting JSON from MongoDB with Sveltetkit

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, svelte, sveltekit

**UPDATE 08-25-21**

I am experimenting with SvelteKit with an Atlas MongoDB endpoint. I have setup a MongoDB account and loaded the Sample Dataset, which includes an 'sample_airbnb' database with a 'listingsAndReviews'. I am struggling getting JSON back to structure and style.

Ive installed mongodb via npm.

In an effort to just get something back to confirm the query, I have created:

**/src/lib/db.js**

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

export async function init() {

    const uri = "mongodb+srv://careyestes:fLKFXP6fDjpGh6Z@Cluster0.vmomo.mongodb.net/Cluster0?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
    const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

    return client.connect(err => {
        const collection = client.db("sample_airbnb").collection("listingsAndReviews");
        console.log(collection)
        return {
            collection
        }
    });
}
```

**/src/routes/index.js**

```
import { init } from '$lib/db'

export async function get(request) {
    
    const { collection } = await init()
    const listings = await collection.find()
    if(listings) {
    return {
            status: 200,
            body: {
                listings: listings
            }
        }
    } else {
        return {
            status: 500,
            body: {
                error: "Could not retrive db listing"
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'collection' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.
```

If I am going about this at the wrong angle, let me know. I can't find a direct tutorial for how to query mongoDB via SvelteKit.

I am not clear on the best way to query the db to get JSON results.

*FWIW: I have used the mongoDB connection test and confirmed the connection criteria is correct. I also tried creating a store directory and exporting a variable that way and still could not get anywhere.*

I have updated the db.js code aboev as per directed. I am still getting the same error. I added a console log which is returning an array but it doesnt appear to be what I need.

**Console.log**

Cannot destructure property 'collection' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.

```
Collection {
  s: {
    db: Db { s: [Object] },
    options: {
      raw: false,
      promoteLongs: true,
      promoteValues: true,
      promoteBuffers: false,
      ignoreUndefined: false,
      bsonRegExp: false,
      serializeFunctions: false,
      fieldsAsRaw: {},
      writeConcern: [WriteConcern],
      readPreference: [ReadPreference]
    },
    namespace: MongoDBNamespace {
      db: 'sample_airbnb',
      collection: 'listingsAndReviews'
    },
    pkFactory: { createPk: [Function: createPk] },
    readPreference: ReadPreference {
      mode: 'primary',
      tags: undefined,
      hedge: undefined,
      maxStalenessSeconds: undefined,
      minWireVersion: undefined
    },
    bsonOptions: {
      raw: false,
      promoteLongs: true,
      promoteValues: true,
      promoteBuffers: false,
      ignoreUndefined: false,
      bsonRegExp: false,
      serializeFunctions: false,
      fieldsAsRaw: {}
    },
    readConcern: undefined,
    writeConcern: WriteConcern { w: 'majority' },
    slaveOk: false
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `init()` function doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2):

The original answer is correct. The issue is that you are returning the collection in the **callback** function, not the **init** function. client.close(); may also cause errors when you try run the find function in your index.js file, so you should remove that.

You will need to replace this line:

```
client.connect(err => {
```

with

```
return client.connect(err => {
```

**OR**

Refactor your code to use the await keyword, which means you won't have to use the 2 return statements:

```
    const connection = await client.connect();
    const collection = client.db("sample_airbnb").collection("listingsAndReviews");
    return {
       collection
    }
```

Comment: I have applied the above suggestions and still have the same error.